# Extending isomorphisms between $*$-algebras to $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I'm quite sure I am correct about this but at the moment I can't think for the life of me why. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $*$-algebras and there are $*$-homomorphisms $\pi_1 \colon A \to \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}_1)$ and $\pi_2 \colon B \to \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}_2)$ and a unitary map $U \colon \mathcal{H}_1 \to \mathcal{H}_2$ such that $U \pi_1(A) U^* = \pi_2(B)$.

Does this imply that the $C^*$-algebras $\overline{\pi_1(A)}^{\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H_1})}$ and $\overline{\pi_2(B)}^{\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}_2)}$ are $*$-isomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your unitary goes from $\mathcal H_2\to\mathcal H_1$, or equivalently is an element in the set of intertwiners $(\mathcal B(\mathcal H_2),\mathcal B(\mathcal H_1))$. Given this, the unitary in question allows you to *identify* operators between those two Hilbert spaces, i.e. it induces a bijection through its adjoint action. Any Cauchy net in $\pi_1(A)$, which converges in $\overline{\pi_1(A)}$ by completeness, is then mapped to a Cauchy net in $\pi_2(B)$, which converges in $\overline{\pi_2(B)}$ for the same reason. A moment's thought shows you that these limits, say $x$ and $y$ respectively, are linked by the unitary $U$, i.e. $y = UxU^*$ and that the boundary is mapped onto the boundary. All this is then enough to conclude that those two C*-algebras are $*$-isomorphic.

Comment: Yes the problem I had was that if $(T_i)_{i \in I}$ were Cauchy  then $(U T_i U^*)_{i \in I}$ is also Cauchy. But this is clear because consider $\xi \in \mathcal{H}_1$ with norm one such that $\|T\| - \varepsilon \leq \|T \xi\| \leq \|T\|$ for very small $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $\|T\| - \varepsilon \leq \|T \xi\| = \|U T U^* (U\xi)\| \leq \|UTU^*\|$.

Comment: or $\Vert UTU^*\Vert\leq\Vert T\Vert$, since $\Vert U\Vert = 1$ (indeed $\Vert UTU^*\Vert = \Vert T\Vert$).

Comment: $\Vert T\Vert = \Vert U^*UTU^*U\Vert\leq\Vert UTU^*\Vert$.

Comment: I realised that just after I asked it :)